Why does LinearGradient() fail to work in a ZStack > NavigationStack?
I am new to SwiftUI and hoping to understand why LinearGradient() is not working when applied to a ZStack, followed by a NavigationStack.
Any guidance would be appreciated!
var body: some View {
    
    ZStack {
        LinearGradient(colors: [.pink, .purple], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section{
                    Text("Preferred wake up time")
                        .font(.title)
                    
                    DatePicker("Enter a time", selection: $wakeUp, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                        .labelsHidden()
                }
                
                Section{
                    Text("Desired amount of sleep")
                        .font(.title)
                    
                    Stepper("\(sleepAmount.formatted()) hours", value: $sleepAmount, in: 4...12, step: 0.25)
                }
                
                Section {
                    Text("Daily coffee intake")
                        .font(.title)
              
                    
                    Picker("Cups of coffee", selection: $coffeeAmount) {
                        ForEach(0..<21) {
                            Text("\($0)")
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Section {
                    Text("Recommended bedtime")
                        .font(.title)
                    Text(sleepResults)
                        .font(.title3)
                }
            }
            
            .navigationTitle("Better Rest")
        }
    }
}

I attempted to apply LinearGradient() within the above ZStack, followed by a NavigationStack. This did not return any results (aka none of the colors I applied appeared). I then tried applying this in various sections of the form, but none filled the edge-to-edge screen.

The NavigationStack has its own background and this blocks the visibility of the gradient. See Using a custom background behind NavigationStack in SwiftUI for some possible workarounds.

NavigationStack itself has its own background. By inspecting the view hierarchy, one can see that NavigationStack creates a UIKitNavigationController that presents NavigationStackHostingControllers. The latter's view has the system background color, covering up the linear gradient.

You should add backgrounds to the content inside the NavigationStack, not to the navigation stack itself.
The Form also has its own background color, but this is easily disabled by .scrollContentBackground(.hidden).
NavigationStack {
    Form {
        // ...
    }
    .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
    .navigationTitle("Better Rest")
    .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
    .background(.linearGradient(colors: [.pink, .purple], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
}

Note I also added .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar), so that the navigation bar is transparent even when the form is scrolled down. Remove that if you want an opaque navigation bar.
If you navigate to another view, the background will not persist, because that view is also backed by a NavigationStackHostingController. You should add the .background modifier in the destination again, if you want the same background.

This worked perfectly --  thank you so much @Sweeper!!!!
